# Chrome bug with contenteditable and list with display:flex

Tags: html, google-chrome, flexbox, contenteditable

In this snippet, using contenteditable and a list with `display:flex`, cause a strange bug: after adding TWO new lines, all content disappears. It doesn't happen in other browsers.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body contenteditable>
 <ol>
    <li style="display:flex">Row1</li>
    <li style="display:flex">Row2</li>
    <li style="display:flex">Row3 (type enter TWICE after this)</li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/7sLn16mw

Any idea?

Comment: which browser you getting error ?

Comment: Chrome  79.0.3945.88

Comment: try ```<ol contenteditable>``` instead body.

Comment: @HardikChaudhary it works, but in a  complex HTML editing tool I cannot apply content editable only to specific internal elements. Unfortunately also adding a contenteditable <div> container causes the bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is recognized as bug by the Chromium development team:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1038520

Fix in Chrome 81